# How to limit the number of characters per line in a cell in excel 2016

Tags: cells, word-wrap

I am trying to combine multiple cells into one, however when combining,  I can only have 55 characters per line. Is there a way to create a word wrap that will keep my data to 55 characters per line?

Comment: Is this a space constraint? if so, simply use Home>Wrap Text and set the column to fit 55 "W" characters and this will give you At Least 55 characters space. Note: to have Exactly 55 characters you will need to use a Mono-spaced font. I.e. most common fonts would fit many more "I"s in the space 55 "W"s would occupy. If it's an actual "count" requirement then VBA code may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

idk if this will help or not but you can see the steps in the following link : https://www.causal.app/excel/limiting-number-of-characters-in-a-cell

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).